# Only some Font Awesome 5 icons work in Qt Qml

Tags: qt, qml, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I am trying to show Font Aweseom 5 (5.10.2) icons in a Qt Qml label:

```
Label {
    text: "\uf2bb" + " x " + "\uf002"
    font.family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"
    //font.weight: Font.Normal
}
```

On Windows all icons work as expected. But on all other platforms (macOS, Android, iOS) only some icons (for instance `\uf2bb`) are shown while others (`\uf4b4`) do not work and a simple rectangle is shown instead. But all icons work on all platforms when QWidgets are used.

I verified that the "Font Awesome 5 Free" font is installed in the QFontDatabase using this utility list view:

```
ListView {
    anchors.fill: parent;
    model: Qt.fontFamilies()

    delegate: Item {
        height: 40;
        width: ListView.view.width
        Label {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: modelData;
        }
    }
}
```

Has anyone an idea why some icons work in Qml, while others don't?

Regards,

Comment: Problem solved: Qt produces the same font name for all Font Awesome styles (except on Windows where every style has a unique name). Thus, only the last added font style is kept.

Comment: Can you please answer your question with that, including what you did to make it work? I suspect the answer will be really useful to a lot of people.

Answer (score 1):

Either setting the font weight to `Font.Black` or the font's style name to `"Solid"` fixes the problem:

```
Label {
    text: "\uf2bb" + " x " + "\uf002"
    font.family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"
    font.weight: Font.Black // this does the trick
}

Label {
    text: "\uf2bb" + " x " + "\uf002"
    font.family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"
    font.styleName: "Solid" // this does the trick
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem with https://fontforge.org/

On file **fa-solid-900.ttf** I modified the field `WWS Family` (under tab TTF Names) from `Font Awesome 5 Free` to `Font Awesome 5 Free Solid`

Maybe Qt for Android uses this field and without modification the value is the same for **fa-regular-400.ttf** and **fa-solid-900.ttf**

Hope it helps